# Помогите решить задачу PascalABC

Tags: pascal

```
Program eskketit;
var a:string;
    i,k:integer;
begin
   writeln('Введите предложение:');
   Read(a);
   for i:=1 to length(a) do
      if (a[i] = ' ') and (a[i+1] = 'а') then k:=k+1;
   write(k);
end.
```

Пробовал так решить задачу, но если допустим первое слово начинается на "а", то код уже работает не правильно.

Comment: Вы забыли добавить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавьте условие начала строки

```
if (i = 1 or a[i-1] = ' ') and (a[i] = 'а') then k:=k+1;
```

Или, более понятно:

```
if (a[i] = 'а') and (i = 1 or a[i-1] = ' ') 
then k:=k+1;
```

> Если текущий символ 'a' в начале строки или после пробела

Answer (score -2):

Исправьте это:
`if (a[i] = ' ') and (a[i+1] = 'а')`

на это:
`if (a[i] = 'а') and (i = 1 or a[i-1] = ' ')`

Comment: Так тут же string, такой массив идет с 1

Comment: Нет, **string** это массив символов

Comment: string в паскале начинается с 1го символа

Comment: По нулевому индексу раньше хранился размер строки, сейчас строки могут быть длинее 255, но это не точно)

Comment: Извините, вы были правы